# Problem with httpOnly cookie between Laravel and next

Tags: laravel, api, next.js, postman

I'm creating an App using Laravel and Nextjs. Laravel is running in http://localhost:5001/ and NextJs in http://localhost:3000/.

In laravel when I login a user I return a httpOnly cookie:

```
 return AuthResource::make([
            'user' => [
                'id' => $user->id,
                'first_name' => $user->first_name,
                'last_name' => $user->last_name,
                'user_name' => $user->full_name,
                'email' => $user->email
            ]
        ])->response()->withCookie($cookie);
```

The config cors is:

```
'paths' => ['api/*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,
```

and Session driver is redis:

```
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
```

When I tested the endpoint with postman is working the JWT cookie and I can see it:

[image]

But in the browser (chrome) I can see the cookie in the response but it's not set in the browser (application tab)

[image]

[image]